# Interface listener Null Exception

Tags: java, android

At my adapter, when i tried to call listener.onDataClick it throws null pointer exception. How to fix it? here is my code

Interface-

```
interface OnDataClickListener {
    void onDataClick(App data,boolean h);
}
```

Fragment-

```
public class HttpFragment extends Fragment implements OnDataClickListener{
...
    List<App> appu = new ArrayList<>();
 OnDataClickListener p;
...
 public View onCreateView-
     WifiShareAdapter appsAdapter = new WifiShareAdapter(this.getContext(), appu,p);
        recyclerview.setAdapter(appsAdapter);
...
  @Override
    public void onDataClick(App data,boolean h) {
        if(h)
            appShare.add(data);
    else
            appShare.remove(data);
            }
```

Adapter-

```
 OnDataClickListener listener;
public WifiShareAdapter(Context context, List<App> apps, OnDataClickListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.apps = apps;
        this.listener = listener;
    }
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AppViewHolder holder, int position) {
 listener.onDataClick(apps.get(position),true);
```

Exception

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.appsharer.OnDataClickListener.onDataClick(com.example.appsharer.App, boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method

**NullPointerException** is thrown when program attempts to use an object reference that has the **`null`** value.
At first pass `this`.

```
 WifiShareAdapter appsAdapter = new WifiShareAdapter(this.getContext(), appu,this);
```

Then in Adapter class

```
OnDataClickListener listener;

public WifiShareAdapter (Context context, ...,OnDataClickListener listener)
{
  
  this.listener = listener;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not registering the listener that's why you are getting the nullponter exception.

You can use the interface like

```
`public interface DatabaseCallback {
public DatabaseCallback listener = null;

/**
 *
 * @param result
 */
void onSuccessresponse(String result);

/**
 *
 * @param result
 */
void onFailureresponse(String result);
```

}

Registering the listener

```
 public class RegisterListner {
public static DatabaseCallback listener;

/**
 *
 * @param mlistner
 */
public static void setRegisterListner(DatabaseCallback mlistner) {
    listener = mlistner;

}

/**
 *
 * @param result
 * @param code
 */
public static void sendResult(String result, int code) {
    if (code == 0) {
        listener.onSuccessresponse(result);
    } else {
        listener.onFailureresponse(result);
    }
}
```

}

In Activity or Adapter

```
RegisterListner.setRegisterListner(this);
```

Returning the Result

```
RegisterListner.sendResult("Yes",0)
```

`